# Unable to get CSS variables to work in any browser

Tags: css, css-variables

I am having trouble getting CSS variables to work, I am doing the following:

```
:root {
  --base: #ffcd600;
  --spacing: 10px;
  --blur: 10px;
}

img {
  padding: var(--spacing);
  background: var(--base);
}
```

However I am seeing the element inspector as shown below:

```
   img {
      padding: var(--spacing);
      background: var(--base);
    }
```

Comment: Your base colour `#ffcd600` has too many letters / digits for hex. You need to remove one of those values (so that there are a total of 6 letters / digits after the hash). Then your code will work as expected. And yes, you will see the variables in the inspector, though they will still take effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--base: #ffcd600;
```

too many characters in your hexadecimal value.

Answer (score -1):

A little confused as to what you're asking. But when using the provided code I did not encounter any issues, with one exception. As Obsidian has stated your Hex has one extra value. Removing the extra 0 will work. 
If you were to test it like so, what do you see?

```
:root {
  --base: #ffcd60;
  --spacing: 10px;
}
h1 {
  color: var(--base);
  padding: var(--spacing);
}
```

If this also does not display correctly then have you tried clearing your cache?